# Maven/GAE - Missing some Datanucleus classes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, datanucleus

I have been struggling for hours trying to figure the good pom.xml out for my already existing GAE/J project.

Here is the "most working" version of my pom.xml (and it's probably terribly messy):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- The Basics -->
<groupId>com.***</groupId>
<artifactId>***</artifactId>
<version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>***</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>

    <!-- GAE SPECIFICS -->
    <!-- Upload to http://test.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com by default -->
    <gae.application.version>test</gae.application.version>
    <gae.version>1.6.1</gae.version>
    <gae.sdk.version>1.6.1</gae.sdk.version>
    <gae.port>8888</gae.port>
    <datanucleus.gae.version>1.0.10</datanucleus.gae.version>
    <datanucleus.version>3.0.5</datanucleus.version>

    <!-- Web -->
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <!-- Data -->
    <jdo.version>2.3-ea</jdo.version>

    <!-- Validation -->
    <validation.version>1.0.0.GA</validation.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

    <!-- Utils -->
    <log.version>1.6.1</log.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <mockito.version>1.8.5</mockito.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Google App Engine meta-package -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jdo.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- J2EE Servlet API. We need it to compile IndexServlet class. You can 
        probably remove it, if you don't explicitly use Servlets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Make use of JSP tags. Remove, if you don't use JSPs -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- These dependencies are here just for enabling logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GAE libraries for local testing as described here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/howto/unittesting.html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- This plug-in "enhances" your domain model objects (i.e. makes them 
            persistent for datanucleus) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Make sure this path contains your persistent classes! -->
                <mappingIncludes>**/model/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <api>JPA</api>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                            <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${jdo.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/appengine-web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The actual maven-gae-plugin. Type "mvn gae:run" to run project, "mvn 
            gae:deploy" to upload to GAE. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>${gae.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Upload application to the appspot automatically, during release:perform -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <goals>gae:deploy</goals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Java compiler version -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/***/integration/**/*Test.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <!-- We can configure our integration server to activate this profile and 
        perform gae:deploy, thus uploading latest snapshot to the http://1.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com 
        automatically -->
    <profile>
        <id>integration-build</id>
        <properties>
            <gae.application.version>stage</gae.application.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- This profile will activate automatically during release and upload 
        application to the http://2.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com (We might 
        want to set the 2nd version as our applications Default version to be accessible 
        at http://<applicationName>.appspot.com) -->
    <profile>
        <id>release-build</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <!-- During release, set application version in appengine-web.xml to 
                2 -->
            <gae.application.version>release</gae.application.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And this is what I get when running `mvn gae:run`:

```
WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/***-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/OMFContext:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.OMFContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityManagerFactory.<init>(DatastoreEntityManagerFactory.java:63)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(DatastorePersistenceProvider.java:35)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:564)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:879)
[...]
Jan 17, 2012 11:24:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Jan 17, 2012 11:24:55 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Jan 17, 2012 11:24:55 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

I changed the version of datanucleus-core so that OMFContent could be found but then it fails even more badly.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

GAE v1.0.10 needs DataNucleus v1.1.x

GAE v2.x needs DataNucleus 3.x

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, by GAE you mean datanucleus-appengine?

Comment: Hi again, I am sorry I am getting so confusedm but could you please tell me exactly what dependencies you are talking about ?

FYI, The dependency tree is there: https://gist.github.com/1636358.

Comment: The jars of the DataNucleus project (except datanucleus-appengine, which is Googles). All of this is in the GAE docs

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong but what you are saying is (based on the dependency tree linked above):

every org.datanucleus:*.jar should be either in version 1.1.x or 3.x depending on com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine version?

Comment: Well, I decided just to stop trying to deploy to app engine and started over the project. This kind of difficulties is really annoying/demotivating.

Comment: THe Wiki http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo tells you exactly how you use v2 of their plugin. If that isn't clear enough then its for you to define *what* is unclear, and then things can be improved. Why people downvote this answer is for them to answer ...